# Problems in SuitePay payment gateway

Tags: php, payment, gateway

I was integrating `SuitePay` payment method in my website. But I was having problems in my code. I was using the code `SuitePay` sent me. Here is the code. This code is for the test mode. And when I was using testing credit card details It's not showing anything.

```
<?php

echo "<pre>";

 if(isset($_POST))
 {
  date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

  $login = "kecFMyP5hWV";
  $api_public_key = "7ckSM61sLitczpgAiMV6yzX4BKH6tdRq";
  $devid = "0720be9f77c28aeebae29032185e1927348c37e1";
  $mid = "99";   // this changes to live mid after testing period

  $creditcard =$_POST['creditcard'];
  $month = $_POST['month'];  // MM

  $year = $_POST['year'];     // YY - remeber 2 digits
  $cvv = $_POST['cvv'];
  $amount = $_POST['amount'];
  $ch_name=$_POST['ch_name'];
  $opt = "";

  $data = array (
   'user_login' => $login,
   'public_key' => $api_public_key,
   'developerid' => $devid,
   'transaction_data' => array (
                   'mid' => $mid,
                   'creditcard' => $creditcard,
                   'cardfullname' => $ch_name,
                   'cvv' => $cvv,
                   'currency' => 'USD',
                   'month' => $month,
                   'year' => $year,
                   'orderid' => '01234567890TEST25',    /// must be a unique number each time a sale is done
                   'amount' => $amount
           )
  );

  $json_data = json_encode($data);
  //var_dump($json_data);
  $curlURL = "https://qa.suitepay.com/api/v2/card/sale/";    // qa.suitepay.com for testing and api.suitepay.com for the live

  $ch = curl_init($curlURL);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
  //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
  //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

  //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4);
  //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');

  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  $arresult = json_decode($response,true);
  //print_r (curl_errno($ch));

  if(curl_errno($ch))
  {
   echo 'curl errno:'
         var_dump(curl_errno($ch));
      echo 'curl error:'
      var_dump(curl_error($ch));
  }

  curl_close($ch);
  echo 'response:'
  var_dump($response);

 }

echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ashwini Sharma: This may be tls issue. You have to use TLSv1.2 to meet the right requirements of the server you are connecting to which is of suitepay. Just add

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
```

before

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Here 6 is for TLSv1.2. The added line will force server to use TLSv1.2 to connect with suitepay server.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

    //print_r($_POST); die();          date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
     $login = "Re3WEyvhbrZ";   $api_public_key =    "4EzLWmvjKMcBgjgKniv6CnRHbAq3rEw5";   $devid =   
"3206d2aa76e1be0e61c83420a31a03b27a953a18";   $mid = "240001";   // 
this changes to live mid after testing period
     $creditcard =$_POST['card_number'];   $month =    $_POST['exp_date_month'];  // MM
     $year = $_POST['exp_date_year'];     // YY - remeber 2 digits      $cvv = $_POST['cvv2'];   $amount = $_POST['amountpay'];     
$ch_name=$_POST['card_name'];       $address=$_POST['address'];
    $country=$_POST['country'];     $city=$_POST['city'];
    $state=$_POST['state'];     $zip=$_POST['zip'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];     $email=$_POST['email'];
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];     $lname=$_POST['lname'];
    $ipadderss=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];;

     $data = array (    "user_login" => $login,    "public_key" =>    $api_public_key,    "developerid" => $devid,    "transaction_data"
=>    array (
                  "mid" => $mid,
                  "creditcard" => $creditcard,
                  "cardfullname" => $ch_name,
                  "cvv" => $cvv,
                  "currency" => "USD",
                  "month" => $month,
                  "year" => $year,
                  "orderid" => rand(),    /// must be a unique number each time a sale is done
                    "ipaddress" => $ipadderss,
                    "bcountry" => $country,
                    "baddress" => $address,
                     "bcity" => $city,
                     "bstate" => $state,
                     "bzip" => $zip,
                   "cphone" => $phone,
                  "cfirstname" => $fname,
                   "clastname" => $lname,
                    "cemail" => $email,
                  "amount" => $amount
          )   );
     $json_data = json_encode($data);   //var_dump($json_data);      $curlURL = "https://qa.suitepay.com/api/v2/card/sale";    //   
qa.suitepay.com for testing and api.suitepay.com for the live      
$curl = curl_init();    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $curlURL);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");   curl_setopt($ch,
CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,    6);  //curl_setopt($curl,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    curl_setopt($curl,
CURLOPT_POST, 1);    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
$json_data);
       //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC ) ;    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);    //curl_setopt($curl,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);    //curl_setopt($curl,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);    // curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER,
true);  //This option returns some    data to the screen    //
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,    "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;
MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");    //curl_setopt($curl,
CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, ''); //write cookies.  empty string to ignore.  
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, ''); //read cookies   
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, '1');    //curl_setopt($curl,
CURLOPT_NOPROXY, 1); // causes POST to fail    //curl_setopt($curl,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Expect:"));    //curl_setopt($curl,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
       $response = curl_exec($curl);     $arresult = json_decode($response,true);    // curl_close($curl);    // return  
$response;  //$response = curl_exec($ch);    // $arresult =
json_decode($response,true);   //print_r (curl_errno($ch));
     if(curl_errno($curl))   {    echo 'curl errno:';
        var_dump(curl_errno($curl));

     echo 'curl error:';
     var_dump(curl_error($curl));   }
     curl_close($curl);   echo 'response:';   var_dump($response);
    }         




       ?>
```

Comment: Please format your answer properly, this is unreadable. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: and add some explanations what it does to it. This is nice for other users and the asker